# Allow frame from different domain with MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-headers, x-frame-options

I am trying to load google maps into an iframe using MVC5 but I am getting blocked with the error

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/maps?cid=XXXXX' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

So after much searching, I have tried the following:

- Adding `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;` to the `Application_Start` in global.ascx
- Creating an attribute (have tried this with and without the setting in global.ascx):

  ```
  public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
      if (filterContext != null)
      {
          filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "ALLOW-FROM https://www.google.com";
          base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
      }
  }
  ```
- trying the attribute `OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)` instead of `OnActionExecuted`
- remove it in the web.config:

  ```
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
      </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  ```

Is there something I'm missing? how do I get rid of this http header (or at least change it to allow maps)?

**Update**

I have just checked the headers being sent and they are correct in that they either say

> X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.google.com

Or aren't there at all if I remove the attribute but keep the global.ascx update

Yet when I run the page and see these headers, it is still giving me the SAMEORIGIN error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I have been completely stupid and misunderstood how x-frame-options work.  It is to stop your site page being shown on another site through an iframe.

So the x-frame-options http header that I was getting for SAMEORIGIN was actually coming from google.  I thought that as the url was returned from their places api I could just use it, but apparently you can only link to it.

Creating a new map api key and enabling the maps embed api, I was able to use the place_id instead and call the following url into the iframe:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=place_id:PLACE_ID
```

And this would show without me getting the header (or doing anything extra to my headers).

I'll leave this here just in case anyone is as daft as I am